# Export Chart to PDF with image

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a problem with exporting a chart in pdf.
Look at the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianCC/MLasL/28/

```
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    width: 600,
                    height: 90,
                    borderColor: '#000000',
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    type: 'line',
                    spacingLeft: 175 
                },
...
```

The chart should export with an image embedded, but the image is not exported into pdf. 
I am using ASP.What is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: what server side language are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting tool use chart without dynamic content, like using renderer in callback. So you should use renderer in load chart event which add your image during initialization of chart. (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load)

Take look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/MLasL/38/

```
events:{
                    load:function(){
                     this.renderer.image('http://87.106.176.87/Carel/Content/images/logo.jpg', 1, 1, 150, 50).add();

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how i solve it :

- use [google canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/)
  It takes a URL to a SVG file or the text of an SVG file, parses it in JavaScript, and renders the result on a Canvas element.
- render your chart svg to the canvas using

  ```
   canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'),getSVG());
  ```
- convert what you have in the canvas to image

  ```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas") ; 
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); //img is data:image/png;base64
     img = img.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
  ```
- render your image to a hidden field

  ```
    $("hidden field").val(img) ;
  ```
- to convert this string to byte array do

  ```
   Dim imageFile() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(YOUR HIDDEN FIELD .Value)
  ```

**UPDATE**

get the highcharts SVG

- use the `chart.getSVG()` method

[Highcharts API](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-object)

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-getsvg/)

- or simply use `$(your svg).html()`